# How can I use .Net Core Class Library (.NetStandard v1.5) into .Net Framework 4.6.2 Application

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

According to [Mapping the .NET Platform Standard to platforms](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/Documentation/architecture/net-platform-standard.md#mapping-the-net-platform-standard-to-platforms) .NET Platform Standard 1.5 have to be compatible with .NET Framework 4.6.2. I have tried to use it (make new .NET Platform Standard class library, then new .Net Framework 4.6.2 console application), but the library is not recognized. What I am doing wrong?

project.json in class library:

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",

  "dependencies": {
    "NETStandard.Library": "1.5.0-rc2-24027"
  },

    "frameworks": {
        "netstandard1.5": {
            "imports": "dnxcore50",
            "buildOptions": { "embed": "true" }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does it need to be `netstandard1.6` TFM (target framework moniker)

Comment: Sorry, it is .Net 4.6.2.  What should I have in "frameworks" in project.json?

Comment: Can you share both `project.json` files?

Comment: @DavidPine The .Net Framework 4.6.2 is normal application, not .net Core

Comment: I think you're stuck targeting `net46` for now

Comment: Is it not possible for now?  Will be possible in the future?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113142/discussion-between-david-pine-and-mottor).

Answer (score 1):

If you get the latest .net core RTM release and the Update 3 VS tooling, things are a *little* nicer than they were during the RC period.  Still don't have easy project references from csproj referencing xproj - but, you can get things to talk by packing up the xproj output into a nuget package, then using the package manager to install that package.  Also, you shouldn't need the imports on the framework, nor the dependency on netstandard.library, at least I don't.  Here's how I've done it:

- Create a .cmd file which will package the nuget files and two copy the output files to the folder where the package manager is expecting them.  Here's that script, I call it makeNuget.cmd:

  IF "%1" == "%2" (

  dotnet pack --no-build --configuration %1 -o ../%3

  xcopy %4 "...\%3\lib\%5\" /Y

  )
- Add a postbuild script in the project.json of the xproj to run the script

  "scripts": {
  "postcompile": [
    "makeNuget.cmd %compile:Configuration% Release packages\%project:Name% %compile:OutputDir% %compile:TargetFramework%"
  ]
  }

This should leave you with a nuget package in the packages\[projectName]\ folder at the root of your solution, with the binaries in the packages\[projectName]\lib\[targetFramwork]\ folder

- Now, you need to add the packages folder as a package source, so first open the package manager console, then click the little gear to add a package source (or Ctrl+Q, package sources, Enter).  Then click the add button, name this source, browse or type in the packages directory and hit ok.
  [image]
- In the package manager console, make sure both your package source and  project are selected in the drop downs at the top.
- install-package [your package name]

AFAIK, that's as good as it gets at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need .Net Framework 4.6.2 app?

I just created PCL (Portable class library) targeting .NETStandard1.4 and I can use it in WPF app which is targeting .NET Framework 4.6.1. 
Here is how my project.json looks like in PCL project:

```
{
  "supports": {},
  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.NETCore.Portable.Compatibility": "1.0.1",
    "NETStandard.Library": "1.6.0"
  },
  "frameworks": {
    "netstandard1.4": {}
  }
}
```