# Compile/Run single C# file on macOS

Tags: c#, macos, .net-core, csc

I'm able to develop .NET Core based C# apps through VS for Mac, and now I've created a "compiler" which generates C# for a language I created. I would like to at least run the output (a single file called Program.cs) and hopefully compile it to an executable on macOS.

On Windows, this can be done with:

```sh
csc /optimize /t:exe /out:Program.exe Program.cs
```

Oddly enough, this exact command works identically on macOS too, and generates a Windows executable. What I would like is this equivalent for a mac executable. However, the [csc documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-options/target-compiler-option) states that the only compiler targets are 'library', 'module', and Windows apps.

To clarify, I don't want to run the code at runtime, but to build an executable from code that was generated (as a string) at runtime.

Comment: Even on Windows the correct way to do this is to use Roslyn directly, not through the `csc` command

Comment: If you want to run C# code like scripts, you may find the code useful I used here to do exactly that:  https://gitlab.com/Syroot/NintenTools.Bfres/blob/master/src/Syroot.NintenTools.Bfres.Script/Program.cs

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Compiling and Running code at runtime in .Net Core 1.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37526165/compiling-and-running-code-at-runtime-in-net-core-1-0)

Comment: @Ray that code used Roslyn deep down. It's not useful since it doesn't contain any explanation of what it does or which parts are relevant

Comment: Chech the [Scripting API samples](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/wiki/Scripting-API-Samples) in the Roslyn repo. This document shows how to parse and execute anything from expressions to full scripts

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos That's why I posted it as a comment, not an answer. I'm not sure what the OP wants to achieve, maybe it's that.

Comment: To clarify, I don't want to run the code in Program.cs at runtime. I'm looking to generate an executable from it at runtime. Some of the links in comments look promising, it'll take me a minute to dig through and see if the question's been answered.

Comment: @DeeBo the linked answer shows how to run a script or generate an assembly. In both cases you need Roslyn. `csc` calls the Roslyn API

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Running `csc` directly only makes sense when done as a part of a build process, or when running on a platform that supports execution of .Net Framework (or .Net Standard) assemblies - i.e. Windows at the moment, and then only for trivial dependency-free code.

What you need is `dotnet new console` to create the project, put your `Program.cs` inside the project folder, then `dotnet build` will generate the executable (after downloading necessary nuget dependencies etc). To share the executable, use `dotnet publish -c <configuration> -r <runtime> --self-contained true` (for example `<configuratio>` being `Release` and `<runtime>` being `osx-x64`).

This technology is called .Net Native and it's awesome.

Answer (score 0):

You can generate exe/compile (c#) using the terminal if you are on OSX. You can follow [this post](https://blog.motasimfoad.com/post/dotnet/generate_exe/)

It requires :

- Visual Studio For Mac
- A .cs file
- Few lines in terminal

Comment: The post appears to be about generating a Windows executable on a Mac.
My question is about generating Mac executables.